# jstl c:forEach content flashes in (blocks page render)

Tags: jsp, jstl, html-select, flicker

My website is flashing in this select element and it looks tacky, it seems that each element that uses a forEach loop is holding up the rest of the site from loading. Is there a way to make this jstl not block page rendering or not flash the content onto the page?

```
<select id="senderSelect" name="sender">
  <option value="">Select a Sender from List</option>
  <!-- Build Sender Options -->
  <c:forEach items="${SRList}" var="senderList">
      <c:choose>
        <c:when test="${param.sender == senderList.clientID}">
          <option value="${senderList.clientID}" selected>
            <c:out value="${senderList.clientDescription}" />
          </option>
        </c:when>
        <c:otherwise>
          <option value="${senderList.clientID}">
            <c:out value="${senderList.clientDescription}" />
          </option>
        </c:otherwise>
      </c:choose>
  </c:forEach>                 
</select>
```

**UPDATE**

The page loaded normally with the select options hard coded onto the page, there was no flickering.

Comment: How many items does it contain? Apparently it exceeded default response buffer size which is usually 2KB and you used a webbrowser which eagerly presents halfbaked HTML.

Comment: It contains different amounts depending on user, for admin (which im testing) contains ~700+ a normal user probably around 30. And I am using chrome

Comment: Yea, it didn't flash the content when I logged in as a normal user! Is there a workaround for when I'm logged in as admin?

Comment: Okay, so technically your problem is reproducible when having all that HTML hardcoded in JSP instead of conditionally generated with help of JSTL? Nonetheless, 700+ items suggests a different problem. Have you considered an autocomplete dropdown?

Comment: I dont think it would be a problem if it was hardcoded though, the browser would act normal, wouldnt it? No I had not considered an autocomplete dropdown, but ajax in this situation is something I was trying to avoid. But if thats the only option, I might have to.

Comment: Have you confirmed it by testing?

Comment: I hard coded the select options onto the jsp page, and it parsed the page like normal html and did not cause a flicker of loading content.